# Replacing the symbol name in the symbol table to a new longer name in relocatable ELF object file

Tags: c, unix, elf, object-files

This is for a relocatable ELF object file, not fully-linked ELF or ELF shared library.

Currently if there is a program such as `main.c`:

```
int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

and compile with `gcc -c main.c` it will generate a `main.o`.

I want to replace the call to `foo` with `fool` or `food` (a longer name) *after* the object file is already created.

Because currently the relocatable ELF will be broken if we extend past the length 3 of `foo`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to replace the call to `foo` with `fool` or `food` (a longer name) *after* the object file is already created.

This is quite possible, but far from trivial.

First, you need to copy the `.symtab` section to the end of the file, and append the desired string `food\0` to it.

Second, you need to update the section table and replace the offset and length of the original `.symtab` with the offset and size if the section added in previous step.

Last, you need to find the symbol (in the `.symtab` section) and update its `st_name` with the offset of the `food` string added in the first step.

And that's all there is to it.

Comment: "That's all" — masterful understatement!

Comment: I'll try a similar approach and let both you (@JonathanLeffler + Employed Russian) know how it goes, thanks for your help

Comment: @Seoul: On some (most?) systems with ELF, there is a `libelf` with functions to facilitate the reading of ELF object files.  I've not used it; I'm not sure to what extent it makes the creation of valid ELF object files easy, but I expect that the support is there.  If it is available, use it — it will make your life easier.  (A quick search with Google and the term 'libelf' finds lots of useful looking URLs, and mention of 'modify'.)

Comment: (@JonathanLeffler + Employed Russian), Thanks for both your help. I decided to go through the elf header, section header table, the string table, and then update the symbol table by using elf.h and not `libelf`.